# Hide python shell while using tkinter window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there any way to hide python shell while using a tkinter window or turtle window?
While opening py file by clicking the py shell shows every time but I don't need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your Python program using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`. This is specifically designed for this.

Comment: but how to stop quitting app so immediately?

Comment: @HamidFzM You mean how to prevent it from returning from the call immediately while running the program? Sorry, don't know...

Comment: Yes, for example in consul program we put input() and program stops but in this case if we use it we expect a big error!!